# Split packages in different Zip files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

in eclipse I use maven for my projects.
Now, I got my java files in src/main/java in two different packages.

src/main/java
               /a/b/c (here are the java files of the first package)
               /d/e/f (here are the java files of the second package)

When I run maven package, maven puts the java files of the two different packages in one zip file. How can I make them put in two different zip files?

Comment: How comes that you have two branches that coexist even if you are under git?

Comment: Why? What do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by branch?

Comment: I got a branch for java files in eclipse. In that specific branch I have subbranches. In my case two different subbranches.

Comment: With branch I mean folder.

Comment: Ok, call them folders. (GIT) branches are a specific (and different) thing.

Comment: You should call them packages because that is what's under src/main/java normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your two branches should be in separate directories --

```
branch1/src/main/java/a/b/c
branch2/src/main/java/d/e/f
```

You should also do two different projects, one for each branch. Maven doesn't know you have two branches in the same source folder, and I don't think it can separate them out for you.

Comment: But can I leave them in the same project?

Comment: They are supposed to be in the same project.

Comment: Ok, I think a little more detail is needed about what you are trying to do... From the other comments, it sounds like you meant packages instead of GIT branches, which makes a pretty big difference. Why are you wanting to have two different zip files for the code? Are you sure they need to be in the same project?

Comment: I definitely need to have the java files in the same project. Thats for sure. As far as I have understood I need to create a new branch. Yes a branch! What I found is, that if I am in that branch of my current task and I run maven package, the files from the other branch get kind of "ignored" and maven just creates a zip file of the current branch. Is that right? Would it work this way?